# Creating a method that prints different outputs for each value in array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, perceptron

Hi I currently have a array that has all the values of a text file in it and currently have it reading back the file when it runs but I want to produce outputs for each value in the array when it runs. Right now I have one output produced at the end of when the program runs after all the  values have been read back but I want to produce a list of outputs next to each value the program prints back. The output has been created using a training algorithm. Here is my code :

This is where I define my array and my other variables:

```
       `double[] x = new double [3501];`
        double output = 1;

        double netSum;
        double input = 0;            
        double[] x_P = new double[3501];
        double error = input - output;

        Random r = new Random();
        double[] weights = { r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble() };
        double learningrate = 0.1;
        double delta;    enter code here
```

This is where a put the text file into the array :

```
try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 3501; y++)
                {
                   String line = sr.ReadLine();
                   x[y] = Double.Parse(line);
                   Console.WriteLine(line);

                }


            }
```

Here is the algorithm I use to create the output:

```
while (error != 0.01)
            {

                error = 1;

                foreach (double x_value in x)
                {

                    netSum = 0.01;
                    double i = 1;
                    for (i = 1; i < 3501; i++)
                    {

                        netSum =  x[1] * weights[1] + x[2] * weights[2];

                    }

                    x_P[2] = Sigmoid(netSum);
                    output = x_P[2];


                    if (output >= error)
                    {
                        for (i = 1; i < 3501; i++)
                        {


                            delta = x_value - output;
                            error = x[2] - x_P[2];
                            weights[(int)i] += learningrate * delta * x_value;

                            error += Math.Abs(error);


                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(output);

                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }



        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the exception and quit...                
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }



    }

    public static double Sigmoid(double x)
    {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x));
    }


    public double Derivative(double x)
    {

        double s = Sigmoid(x);
        return s * (1 - s);

    }
```

So I basically want outputs printed for each value in x when the values are printed would someone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the `Console.WriteLine` inside your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (double x_value in x)
{
    ...
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```